# Значение статической переменной не сохраняется

Tags: java

У меня есть статическая переменная, а именно матрица вида:

[int индекс][int категория]

Мне нужно увеличивать индекс у конкретной категории.

При нажатии на кнопку создается экземпляр класса, в конструкторе которого вызывается этот метод. Так как эта матрица типа static, ее значение должно сохраняться в таком случае, верно? То есть, при каждом согласии нового класса индекс должен увеличиваться.

Но почему-то значения переменной не сохраняются, и при каждом создании экземпляра ее значение увеличивается с нуля до одного, и так каждый раз. Почему так? Я чего-то не понимаю?

```
    static void setUsed(int str,int category){
    used_words[(used_words_index[0][category-1])++][category-1] = str;
    if (used_words_index[0][category-1] >= 100){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            used_words[i][category-1] = -1;
        }
        used_words_index[0][category-1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы нe показали, как объявлена и назначена переменная `used_words_index`.

Я *догадался*, что Вы присваиваете этой переменной новое значение в конструкторе класса. Этим и объясняется ее ре-инициализация каждый раз при создании нового экземпляра.

```
class MyClass
{
  static int[][] used_words_index = new int[100][100];

  public MyClass() 
  {
    // used_words_index = new int[100][100];
  }
  ...
}
```

---

*N.B. Так как использование слов с корнем "телепат" на этом ресурсе осуждается, я заменил такое слово словом "догадался".*

Comment: Да, именно это я и сделал, в конструкторе класса был цикл, который приравнивал индексы к нулю. Я это обнаружил, когда полез дополнять ответ после Вашего комментария. Спасибо и извините, что потратил время на свою глупость.

Comment: @Straik32423 На здоровье. Успехов!